# Can railing posts be covered with vinyl to protect against weather?

Tags: code-compliance

I am wondering if outdoor staircase wood rails and posts can be covered with vinyl to protect the wood against rot and weather damage. Is there a building code against this in CA?

Comment: Less than perfect coverage, ie totally water-tight, would probably accelerate rot.

Comment: paint would probably work better.

Comment: What does "wood" mean here?